# When should AngularJS on page loaded?

Tags: angularjs

when should load AngularJS on page header or body?

```
<html><head>here?</head> <body>here?</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the AngularJS library either in HEAD or start of the BODY

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to load the JavaScript files just before the closing of the `body` tag to quickly load your visible HTML first.

As a rule of thumb (referenced from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Author_fast-loading_HTML_pages)), follow this structure in your HTML, always:

- **HTML**

  - **HEAD**

    - **LINK** (CSS files required for page appearance. Minimize the number of files for performance while keeping unrelated CSS in separate files for maintenance.)
    - **SCRIPT** (JavaScript files for functions required during the loading of the page, but not any DHTML that can only run after page loads. Minimize the number of files for performance while keeping unrelated JavaScript in separate files for maintenance.)
  - **BODY**: User visible page content in small chunks (tables/divs) that can be displayed without waiting for the full page to download.

    - **SCRIPT**
      Any scripts which will be used to perform DHTML. DHTML script typically can only run after the page has completely loaded and all necessary objects have been initialized. There is no need to load these scripts before the page content. That only slows down the initial appearance of the page load.
      Minimize the number of files for performance while keeping unrelated JavaScript in separate files for maintenance.
      If any images are used for rollover effects, you should preload them here after the page content has downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

https://angularjs.org/ show a example where Angular Js is in the header

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```